# Problems exporting word dashes and quotes from Excel into .csv

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I'm trying to export a spreadsheet to a .csv file and when I do, it takes all of the quotes and dashes and they turn into `?`'s.  I realize it's trying to maintain the Microsoft standard of quotes and dashes (which is incredibly annoying).  How can I get around this so my .csv file contains characters instead of `?`?

the content is coming out as

```
The Healing Book: Facing the Death ? and Celebrating the Life ? of Someone You Love at no extra cost
```

When it should be coming out as

```
The Healing Book: Facing the Death - and Celebrating the Life - of Someone You Love at no extra cost
```

**update**

I'm using Excel 2007

Comment: Which version of excel you are using? You mean exporting is nothing saving as .csv format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it doesn't look that way just because you're using a tool which isn't able to read your character encoding (like, say, a programmer's editor)?  If you open your .csv in MS Word, does it look right?

Comment: When I open the CSV in Excel it continues to show `?`

Comment: This leads me to the answer... it's clear that this symbol is `not supported by Excel` and our customers must have copied from Word instead of typing in Excel.  Thanks!